# Close tab after dialog confirmation

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I created this example of tabs which I want to close after I display confirm dialog and I click `Yes` button.

```
public static Tab testconfirmTabClose(Tab tab)
    {

        tab.setOnClosed(new EventHandler<Event>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event t)
            {
                t.consume();
                // Dialog Stage init
                final Stage dialog = new Stage();
                dialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

                Button btnYes = new Button("Yes");

                btnYes.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                });

                Button btnNo = new Button("No");

                btnNo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent event)
                    {
                        dialog.close();
                    }
                });

                // Layout for the Button
                HBox hbox = new HBox();
                hbox.setSpacing(10);
                hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                hbox.getChildren().add(btnYes);
                hbox.getChildren().add(btnNo);

                // Layout for the Label and hBox
                VBox vbox = new VBox();
                vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                vbox.setSpacing(10);

                // Text
                Text tc = new Text();
                tc.setText("Do you want to quit?");

                // Layout for the Button
                HBox thbox = new HBox();
                thbox.setSpacing(10);
                thbox.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 90));   // Place the dialog text right
                thbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
                thbox.getChildren().add(tc);

                BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

                bp.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 10, 15));
                bp.setTop(null);
                bp.setLeft(vbox);
                bp.setCenter(thbox);
                bp.setRight(null);
                bp.setBottom(hbox);

                Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 140);
                dialog.setScene(scene);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        return tab;
    }
```

I have this issue: When I click on the tab to close it the tab is closed and the confirm dialog is displayed. I cannot "freeze" the tab for the user response. Can you tell me how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no clean way to do this in JavaFX 2.2. JavaFX 8 will (probably) offer a method called `Tab#setOnCloseRequest(...)` that will do what you want. For 2.2, the only way I see right now is pulling the source from OpenJDK and creating your own adapted TabPane implementation - sorry :-/.

Comment: is there a other `EventHandler` which I can use ti get the same effect in JavaFX 2.2? For example calling Dialog when I click on the `X` and calling close() on the active tab?

Comment: I've hacked this support into 2.2 see https://git.eclipse.org/c/efxclipse/org.eclipse.efxclipse.git/tree/bundles/runtime/org.eclipse.fx.e4.controls.fx2/src/org/eclipse/fx/e4/controls/fx2